# A menu div on the left

Tags: asp.net, html, css

How can i add a thin div and customize it to fit on the left side for it to be fit for a menu? I don't even know if a container is necessary, but thats what i understood from looking around the net.

i've tried this, but no luck.

CSS:

```
   #side_container{background:#e0e0e0;}
   #side {float:left; width:180px; padding:10px;}
```

ASP.Net

```
    <div id="side_container">
    <div id="side"></div>
    </div>
```

[Check My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bashar_f/WFKgH/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working correctly. The reason you're not seeing anything is because you haven't floated the container.

Try to also float the container and assign it a width as follows:

```
#side_container { 
    background:#e0e0e0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I have added this to a jsFiddle to demonstrate > http://jsfiddle.net/KXmAM/